# Java collections to JSON

Tags: java, json, collections

My program has to output following JSON format:

```
    {   "success": {
        "code": 1,
        "desc": "success"   },
       "response": {
        "res1": [
          {
            "Item": "item1",
            "Description": [
              {
                "desc": "ad1",
                "active": true,
                "details": [
                  {
                    "Type": "Type1",
                    "Count": 2,
                    "Status": true
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "TYpe2",
                    "Count": 3,
                    "Status": false
                  },
                  ]
              },
              {
                "desc": "item2",
                "active": true,
                "details": [
                  {
                    "Type": "Type1",
                    "Count": 4,
                    "Active": true
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
            "Item": "item2",
            "Description": [
              {
                "desc": "d2",
                "Active": true,
                "details": [
                  {
                    "Type": "Type3",
                    "Count": 6,
                    "Active": true
                  },
                ]
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
   } 
}
```

I have wrote following to create this json format

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> m1 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> m3 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
```

For creating the mentined JSON format, I tried to put m3 and m2 in m1. But since these are not with same type, it won't allow to put.

I am using GSON to convert the collection to JSON.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json1 = gson.toJson(m1);
```

My Question is: For creating that JSON format, which collection in Java I have to use?

Comment: I'd use [JsonBuilder](https://json-processing-spec.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/edr/javadocs/javax/json/JsonBuilder.html)

Comment: you could use [org.json](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Comment: I am using GSON for converting to JSON. I am confused about the collections I have to use to create that JSON format.

Comment: You should add what happens when you run your code, so we can see your errors, or what went wrong with what you have posted.

Comment: Instead of <String, String>, you should use <String, Object>.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with a complex JSON structure like that is to create a class with the same structure with properties that represent the underlying arrays as lists. Then, you can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the object(s) to JSON in a straightforward way.

In other words, instead of trying to fit the structure into a combination of complex collections or existing Java classes, create a class that is an exact representation of the data, populate it, and then convert it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me a sample code also. Since I am new to Java, a sample code will help me to understand.

Comment: It's hard to decipher from the given JSON what your data structure is. Each top level field would be represented by an appropriate type (String, Integer, etc.) and arrays of complex types can be represented by lists of types you create as inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

[Why don't you let the code generated for you?](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

After the pojos are created you can of course change the code to tailor your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ResponseWrapper class and build your json accordingly.

Sample code:

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T>{
    private Map<String, T> wrappedObjects = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public ResponseWrapper() {
    }

    public ResponseWrapper(String name, T wrappedObject) {
        this.wrappedObjects.put(name, wrappedObject);
    }
..
..
```

Your json can be built like this:

```
ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper<ResponseWrapper>();

        Items[] item = ....
        //item can itself have Description, etc.
        response.set("res1", (ArrayList) items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for notepad++ and its json view plugin, i can read your json data in proper format. (although your data missing a few brackets)

In my oponion, json structure can be converted into Map but i personally don't like that idea much.
The other way to do is using Java POJO to define your JSON object and then convert it to json. [Excellent example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

OK. We will check your data and create Java POJO for it. It's simple and should be something like this

```
public class YourJsonObj {
    public SuccessObj success;
    public ResponseObj response;
}
```

where SuccessObj and ResponseObj are another structure Classes like this:

```
public class SuccessObj {
    public Integer code;
    public String desc;
}

public class ResponseObj {
    public List<ResObj> res1;
}
```

Another sub class appear: ResObj. All you have to do is continue define it:

```
public class ResObj {
    public String Item;  // << this property's name does't make java happy
    public List<DescriptionObj> Description // << this property's name does't make java happy
}
```

Continue to do this definition till the end of your data. And you got it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to replicate the same hierarchy of the fields in your JSON example.

By the [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library you can convert (in 2 lines of code) your Java object to a JSON object. Please check the following [example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples) (from the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) of the relative project).

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

// Serialization
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  

// ==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```